# Which country could I live the longest at with only $10,000 starting cash and no income?

Tags: budget, money, countries, long-term

If I were to save up $10,000 American dollars and move to another country where the cost of living is very low, how long could I go jobless and survive on the money I brought? Which country would be a good choice so that I could stay the longest?

Assume that I am living as the locals would. I would attempt to fully take part in their culture. I am not buying items as an American would.

The country must not be dangerous. No war, starvation, or xenophobia

Comment: $10k or $1000k, makes no difference, or does it? Is the figure of 10k extraneous?

Comment: Down voted the question because it's not constructive and is asking for opinion.  Some parts of India has the lowest cost of living. You need to do your own tease arch based on your liking, tolerance, your living style, food habits, and thousand other possible factors.

Comment: Would it fit better in Expatriates SE?  @AyeshK I would probably give the benefit of doubt to the OP in that it is not asking for opinions but fact

Comment: Is zenophobia fear of [Zeno of Elia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno_of_Elea), famous for his paradoxes, or is it fear of [Zeno of Citium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno_of_Citium) founder of the Stoic school of philosophy?

Comment: The reason you're likely being downvoted is it's hard to judge.  Dangerous? Some argue America is dangerous.  Australia is generally considered safe, but had a hostage drama 2 days ago.  
Also to 'live as the locals would' - which locals? A lot of 'cheaper' countries have a lot of homeless, and beggars, but also some crazy rich people.  So that makes your question a bit broad.
I like the idea of the question, but currently it doesn't fit the rules in the [help].

Comment: Actually I think we should fear any one who loves knowledge: all the Zeno's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a country that everyone would agree as the cheapest (and better) country.

There is a nice community-contributed index here: http://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/rankings_by_country.jsp

India is the cheapest country per se, but in the northern region, there are some cities that you can spend same, or even more than one would spend in Europe or the U.S.

As mentioned in the comment, it wouldn't matter $10k or $100k.

The link above also has information about housing, food, transport, etc. calculate it to match to your loving style.

The reason I said this can be different from person to person is that, Sri Lanka is also in the list's lowest cost, but almost everyone spends a lot that this minimum. Lives of these countries are very different from each other.

Also, some countries have dual pricing for foreigners and locals. The very same meal would cost twice in the same restaurant, higher ticket prices, minimum rent requirements, and there are several other things to consider.

I have been at Singapore, beating their high expenses, and I have lived in Sri Lanka, matching one would spend in Singapore. It's really up to you.

If you are actually planning to do this, Sri Lanka would be a good choice. Even my next door family is Canadian, lives a very normal local-ish life, and their cost should be about 600-1000 a month (we pay the same monthly rent and shop in same markets so it should be :) ).

Comment: Although my question is "wrong" according to the grand and immutable rules of question asking: you have somehow provided an answer that is undeniably correct. Thank you